# how to update a Rebol3 GUI from a network event

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I have written a test [GUI application](https://github.com/gchiu/RSOChat/blob/master/r3gui-network-test.r3) to see how to update a R3-GUI from a network event.

The server port receives the event from a client, but using

```
set-face window-inputarea msg
```

fails to update the GUI unless I also mouse over or otherwise generate a GUI event.  This then seems to kick off outstanding event handling.

Do I need to send a simulated GUI event to allow this to happen programatically or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the area style so that set-face in this instance does not update the face.

I've updated the example to show it working.

Comment: Turns out that updating the GUI from a network event can trigger a #9910 network error, apparently due to a malformed event/port being somehow injected into the event queue.

Comment: The network event bug has been fixed in Rebol now but updating the GUI is still haphazard due to more GUI bugs.

Comment: Demo here of a r3gui app being updated by TCP events https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy2u5fSbvTk